# How to set LIVY_CONF_DIR in cloudera

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, cloudera-manager, livy

I have installed livy server in cloudera in /usr/share. I want to change set the LIVY_CONF_DIR so that i can manage the config files like log4j.properties.

Cloudera says this is possible but i could not find how to define it.

`https://github.com/cloudera/livy#building-livy`

Snippet from the github

```
Livy Configuration
Livy uses a few configuration files under configuration the directory, which by default is the conf directory under the Livy installation. An alternative configuration directory can be provided by setting the LIVY_CONF_DIR environment variable when starting Livy.
```

Comment: That snippet tells you that you can change the environment variable LIVY_CONF_DIR, for example with a statement such as `export LIVY_CONF_DIR=/some/random/path/where/you/want/to/store/your/own/configurations`. You should check out the default directory though as there are probably files that you need. Why not just edit the files in the default directory?

Comment: That is the exact problem i have, the changes made in the default directory are not getting refelected. In the default directory there are only templates. I tried to create one file without template but those changes does not get reflected when in the process directory after restart of the service. Ideally i was guessing, it was taking some default configurations and changing something in these would help, but it does not.

Comment: Then please include what you have tried so far. What properties did you change? What did you expect to happen? What happened? How did you rename the files in [the conf dir](https://github.com/cloudera/livy/tree/master/conf) exactly? The answer to your question right now is `export LIVY_CONF_DIR=/some/random/path/where/you/want/to/store/your/own/configurations`, but from your comment it looks like that won't help you. Please see [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/352819). You need to show what you want to happen or people will solve a problem that won't help you.

Comment: The LIVY_CONF_DIR is set in the bin folder of livy package 
export LIVY_HOME=$(cd $(dirname $0)/.. && pwd)
LIVY_CONF_DIR=${LIVY_CONF_DIR:-"$LIVY_HOME/conf"}
It considers LIVY_CONF_DIR where the livy binaries are available. 
Checks done:
1. The log4j properties reflect that of hive-server and not of livy. Not sure how it picks that.
2. There are templates in the conf directory provided with the Livy-server package which contains log4j.properties.template for example, moving it as log4j.properties in the conf directory does not yield the desired results.
All the other files are jar files.